# How to loop through and output nested array in Laravel

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

With this sample I am trying to loop through the nested array and output the following information.

```
Collection {#252 ▼   #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => Collection {#258 ▼
          #items: array:4 [▼
            0 => array:3 [▼
              0 => "Stylish Hat"
              1 => "Green"
              2 => "2017-10-16 17:57:49"
            ]
            1 => array:3 [▼
              0 => "Stylish Hat"
              1 => "Blue"
              2 => "2017-10-16 17:57:49"
            ]
            2 => array:3 [▼
              0 => "Stylish Hat"
              1 => "Red"
              2 => "2017-10-16 18:00:24"
            ]
            3 => array:3 [▼
              0 => "Classic Hat"
              1 => "Black"
              2 => "2018-10-16 18:00:24"
            ]
          ]
        }   ] }
```

---

STYLISH HAT

Colors: Green,Blue,Red

Sale Date: 2017-10-16

---

CLASSIC HAT

Colors: Black

Sale Date: 2018-10-16

---

I have tried various ways with no success to output so I'm not sure if my current code is of any value but here is my stab in the dark that is of course completely wrong...

```
@foreach ($hatData->toArray() as $hatStyle => $color => $saleDate)
         <div style="color:#333;font-size:14pt;">
            <b>{{ $hatStyle }}</b>
         </div>
         @foreach($colors as $color)
            <div style="color:#333;font-size:10pt;">
               colors: {{ $color }}
            </div>
            <div>
               Sale Date: {{ $saleDate }}
            </div>
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is struggling with the output of  a nested array with groupBy in Laravel the cleanest way I found to do this was as follows.  The main loop is the groupBy field and the inner loop is the distinct traits of each group.  My collection was also constructed a little differently than the examples above.

I built my array by first grabbing all the records then grouping by my desired field as such.

```
      $mainCollection=records::where('this','=','that')->get();      

      $selected = $mainCollection->map(function ($item) {
          return [
            'mainValue'=>$item->mainValue,
            'itemOne' => $item->itemOne,
            'itemTwo' => $item->itemTwo
          ];
      });

      $mainLoop=$selected->groupBy('mainValue');
```

Then to output I used the following loop

```
      @foreach ( $mainLoop as $ml )

         <div>
            <u>{{ $ml[0]['mainValue'] }}</u>
         </div>

         @foreach( $ml as $item)
            <div>
               {{$item['itemOne']}} - {{ $item['itemTwo'] }}
            </div>
         @endforeach

      @endforeach
```

Not sure if this is too abstract to help anyone else, and maybe its not the best possible way, but it took me a little hunting and piecing together different things I read to understand this.

Answer (score -1):

use groupBy from the collection class like this:

```
$collection = collect([
['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
]);

$grouped = $collection->groupBy('account_id');

$grouped->toArray();

/*
    [
        'account-x10' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Chair'],
            ['account_id' => 'account-x10', 'product' => 'Bookcase'],
        ],
        'account-x11' => [
            ['account_id' => 'account-x11', 'product' => 'Desk'],
        ],
    ]
*/
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby

Comment: Hi, I was looking for more info on how to output not just build the array as I already did that in the previous question I linked.  But this is still a help since I wasnt aware of the grouped->toArray() command.  I have since figured out the output part on my own so not sure how to close this or maybe delete?